# How to use Hudson for building Lithium Tests?

Tags: php, hudson, jenkins, lithium

I am trying to setup hudson to build lithium unit tests.  I guess the command "li3 test tests/cases" should build these cases, but I'm not sure about setting the paths in Hudson. Anyone done continous integration of lithium projects?

Comment: Thanks for correcting, now it's removed. Originally I thought of adding cakephp+hudson integration assuming it follows the same pattern as lithium.Because there's a larger userbase for cake I'd get my answers quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this blog post [Setting up Jenkins with Lithium](http://blog.icambridge.me/post/17027653996/setting-up-jenkins-with-lithium).

**Note**: As you should know (and for those who find this after a google search), Jenkins is the rename of Hudson. [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29#Hudson.E2.80.93Jenkins_Split)

Comment: Oracle would disagree ;) As far as I know Oracle is treating Jenkins as a fork, and Jenkins is treating Hudson as a fork.